# Convert javascript Max function wrapper to function pointer to Math.Max

Tags: javascript

I was at a job interview and they asked me to write a function to find the maximum value in an array in javascript on the whiteboard.
I wrote:

```
function max(a) { return Math.max.apply(Math,a) }
```

They said good, but what if you want to not write out a function and just have max point to Math.max. I said I don't think you can do that. I think they said you could do:

```
var max = Math.max.apply.bind(Math)
```

But when I do that I and call max([1,2]) get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is a object and not a function
```

How are you supposed to do it?

Comment: What exactly does `... just have max point Math.max` mean?

Comment: The goal is to define max in one line that starts with var max= without curly braces or arrow functions. It will work like Math.max but you pass an array of numbers when you call it.

Comment: Right OK, I think I get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want

```
var max = Function.prototype.apply.bind(Math.max, Math);
```

That is, you create a function which will call `Function.prototype.apply` on `Math.max` (like your `Math.max.apply`) with `Math` as first argument, and redirect arguments of the new function (it should be an array) as additional arguments of `Function.prototype.apply`.

Then, `Function.prototype.apply` will call `Math.max` on `Math` spreading its array argument as arguments of `Math.max`.

But of course, much better with ES6 spread operator:

```
Math.max(...iterable);
```

Comment: The question, of course, is "Is there any benefit at all compared to the original solution?" I'm not sure there is - you're making a new function in both cases, and the original syntax is much clearer...

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand why that works. The first parameter to bind is Math.max which will be the "this" in apply, so it will work like Math.max.apply(). And the second bind parameter is Math which will become the first parameter in apply like Math.max.apply(Math). Then the second parameter to apply will be taken from the array parameter you pass to max()

Comment: @nrabinowitz Basically, not. However, in case a script modifies `Math.max`, my first code will continue working.

Comment: slightly shorter way using generics: `var max=eval.apply.bind(Math.max, 0);`